# C# Get the first instance of a complete capital word

Tags: c#

I am running into an issue and am not sure what the solution is.
WHat I need to do is get a string, find the first fully capitalized word eg. (WORD) not (Word) and then split the string on that.

For instance the data looks like this.

```
"Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT"
```

The result needs to be

```
[0] "Text 123 and more Text"

[1] "THIS IS MORE TEXT"
```

Comment: Use Regex to find the string with Capital word (including space).

Comment: This could be done with regular expressions I suppose. `([A-Z]+\s)` should do...

Comment: Is the second half all capitals? i.e. could you just scan from the right instead?

Comment: What should the result be for "A cat sat ON THE MAT"?

Comment: Just wish to point out your selected answer does not give you the output you've specified in your question.  See - https://dotnetfiddle.net/S4ghbj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using [C# Regular Expressions](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html):

```
public static void Main(string[] args
{                 
       string test_1= "Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT";
       string test_2 = @"(\b[^\Wa-z0-9_]+\b)";
       MatchCollection regCol = Regex.Matches(test_1, test_2);
        foreach(var text in regCol )
        {
           Console.WriteLine(text);
        }      
}
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/OZFM88438)

Another way:

```
string test_1= "Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT";
MatchCollection allCaps= Regex.Matches(" " + test_1 + " ", @" [A-Z]* ");
foreach (Match text in allCaps)
{
  Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Or probably:

```
    string test = "Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT";       
   var allCaps = test.Split(' ').Where( w => w == w.ToUpper());

           foreach(var word in allCaps)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
           }
```

Comment: Note the OP want to split on the first match.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is using Regular Expression. Following code gives you all matches with Capital word with Space. You can choose the max length match or update the RegEx based on your further need.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex regex = new Regex("([A-Z]+\s)");
var str = "Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT";
var matches = regex.Matches(str);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Regular Expression `(\b[A-Z]+\b.*)`. (See : https://regex101.com/r/H9K4nC/2)

This expression will grab form the first fully capitalized word to the end of the string.

Then grab the index of the match. Then generate two strings using `substring`

```
string positiveTest = "Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT";
string negativeTest = "this has no matches";
string matchFullCapWord = @"(\b[A-Z]+\b.*)"; //See : https://regex101.com/r/H9K4nC/2/
MatchCollection matches;
Regex reg = new Regex(matchFullCapWord);

matches = reg.Matches(positiveTest);

if(matches.Count > 0)
{
    int splitIndex = matches[0].Index;

    string stringStart = positiveTest.Substring(0, splitIndex -1);
    string stringEnd = positiveTest.Substring(splitIndex);
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/36Vnd4)

Answer (score 0):

You could do by following logic:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string pattern = @"[A-Z]+\s";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    string str = "Text 123 and more Text THIS IS MORE TEXT";

    var matches = regex.Matches(str);
    string firstString = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(matches[0].ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine(firstString);
    string secondString = "";
    foreach (var match in matches)
    {

        if(secondString.Contains(match.ToString()))
           continue;
        secondString = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(match.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(secondString);   
    }
}
```

[Proof of work: Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NbzD5v)